# How to correct the incomplete rotated text

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator, image-scanner

I just started working with OpenCV and want to implement a scanner function,everything went smoothly ahead,I can scan the picture of the file.But when I tried to further enhance my scanner function, I got stuck and couldn't perform incomplete text correction.

[image: sample image (working)]

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", default="scan.jpg",
    help = "10.jpg")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

def cv_show(name,img):
    cv2.imshow(name,img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow()

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

# show the original image and the edge detected image
print("STEP 1: Edge Detection")
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# find the contours in the edged image, keeping only the
# largest ones, and initialize the screen contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) ## 找到轮廓
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
    # can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        print(screenCnt)
        break



# show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
print("STEP 2: Find contours of paper")
cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow("Outline", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def order_points(pts):
    # initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    # such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    # the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    # bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect


def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped
warped = four_point_transform(orig, approx.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)

# convert the warped image to grayscale, then threshold it
# to give it that 'black and white' paper effect
# warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# T = threshold_local(warped, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
# warped = (warped > T).astype("uint8") * 255

# show the original and scanned images
print("STEP 3: Apply perspective transform")
cv2.imshow("Original", imutils.resize(orig, height = 650))
cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: sample image (failing)]

The logic of the contour of the image I obtained is as follows: using approxPolyDP to obtain approximate geometric shapes, then obtaining points with 4 corners for different geometric shapes, and finally using these four points for perspective transformation. If the image is incomplete, I don't know what to do. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide a ready-made solution

Comment: very long post, 2 unrelated photos attached. Please post the specific problem instead of the whole code and try to give only minimal code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "a ready-made solution"... please review [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]